# An expired & re-registered domain causing multiple harmful links across ServerFault

Tags: discussion

While reading an [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/473530/274176) on a canonical question I found out that a domain of our formerly active contributor, [MDMarra](https://serverfault.com/users/10472/mdmarra), has expired and registered by someone else. He has been referencing his blog here and there, leaving behind some links to the domain. Currently the links to `www.mdmarra.com` are either showing some advertisements or redirecting to sites replicating news portals, potentially for phishing purposes.

Is there a way to automatically remove these links from the whole site? What should we do with such cases?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that issue. I confirm the phishing purpose. I visited the site and I got an fake AD from my ISP for a prize.. I will start to point the URL to webarchive like Glorfindel stated.

Comment: Thanks. I did that for one already, but didn't have time to fix them all.

Comment: I think I've now replaced all the links, but couldn't find a way to verify it, because the `url:` search finds both equally.

Comment: oh , thanks a lot, yesterday my job kept me away from here, I wasnt able to do what I wanted to edit

Answer (score 12):

There are [23 such links](https://serverfault.com/search?q=url%3A%22mdmarra.com%22) on the site. Quite a few, but it's well within the size of an (unofficial) community cleanup operation. The [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) can be used to obtain links to snapshots (except that it's currently down for me). If it's a pretty popular site (I didn't hear of it before, but I'm by no means a domain expert), chances are high most of the blog pages have been archived.

It's best not to replace all links at the same time, as to avoid flooding the homepage with bumped old questions. I'm not sure about the best practice on Server Fault, but on other sites I tend to limit the number of edits to old posts to three per day.